# Class' methods and objects. Reference? Smart pointers? Simple initialization?

Tags: c++, object, methods, reference, smart-pointers

I've been delving into the referenciation and smart pointers over the last couple of days and I still can't figure out when to use which.

Especially for the very simple program I am trying to write.
Where the object value shouldn't be shared but only modified trought returning a value of its type from X or Y methods.

If I am not mistaken, references are easier on the memory, but refers only to one thing.
Where as smart pointers are more stable and can be remaped to point at something else.

**First Question:**

For simple alterations to an object like in the example bellow, is it even necessary to create a reference or a pointer?
I suppose that in the long run, as the program adds in complexity, having but initialized objects doing their thing could create latency issues and the likes...

**Second Question:**

As I understand it, refering to an object will aleviate the stress on the memory by refering to the object when used as a parameter in the method instead of copy-pasting the object into it?
Does a smart_ptr does the same-ish?

The header file for class:

```
-Items.h-
class Health_Potion
{
public:
    int qty = 0;

    static int add_health_potion(int current, int add); 

};
```

The cpp file for methods:

```
-Items.cpp-

int Health_Potion::add_health_potion(int current, int add)
{
    int new_current = current + add;

    cout << add << " potion added to your inventory.\n";
    cout << "Quantity available: " << new_current << "\n";
    return current + add;

}
```

The main function:

```
-Main-

int main()
{

// Initializing the method to be used:
// Question: Should this also be stored into a smart_ptr or referenced to?
Health_Potion add_method;
add_method.add_health_potion;
______________________________________________

// The unique_ptr version I got:

std::unique_ptr<Health_Potion> entity(new Health_Potion); //Unique_ptr

entity -> qty = add_method.add_health_potion(rentity -> qty, roll); //returning new value to the pointer through method
______________________________________________

//The reference version I got:

Health_Potion obj1;
int & refqty = obj1.qty; //reference to object of qty created

refqty = add_method.add_health_potion(refqty, roll); //returning new value to the reference through method
}
```

Forgive my newbieness.

And thank your for your time :).

Answer (score 2):

> I still can't figure out when to use which.

When in doubt, use the simplest approach. Only when the simplest approach is inadequate or awkward is there a reason to consider something more complicated (and at that point, you have a starting point for figuring out which to use).

Comment: Hummm... Fair enough. I guess I am overthinking the process for what's needed at the moment. l'll start with the basic and go from there. Thanks.

Comment: Side note for @Erzats and future readers: Anyone who ever feels down about overthinking something should enter "overengineering" into their favorite search portal... Anyone need a teapot that tells you it is a teapot? :)